# Is the union of a collection of uniformly continuous sets uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Suppose $f$ is uniformly continuous on $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$.

Let $X=\cup_{i=1}^n X_i.$

Is $f$ necessarily uniformly continuous on $X$? Is $f$ even necessarily continuous on $X$?

---

Let $f$ be the constant function given by $f(x)=c$ $ $ where $c \in \mathbb{R}$

Let $X_i =[a_i,b_i)$

Then there is a $\delta>0$ such that for each $x_0 \in X_i$ and $|x-x_o|,$ $$|f(x)-f(x_o)|<\varepsilon$$

$$\Rightarrow |c-c|<\varepsilon$$

$$\Rightarrow0<\varepsilon$$

Now, consider $\cup_{n=1}^\infty X_i=[a_1,b_1)\cup[a_2,b_2)\cup...\cup[a_n,b_n)$

Can we say that there exists $\delta>0$ such that for each $x_0 \in X$ and $|x-x_o|,$ $$|f(x)-f(x_o)|<\varepsilon?$$

Comment: No. $f$ could be constant functions on two separate intervals $[0, 1), [1, 2]$. If the constants don't agree, $f$ will be discontinuous.

Comment: @0XLR Is that because those intervals are neither closed nor open?

Comment: Not really. The reason I did not use $[0, 1]$ up there is that if the constants don't agree, $f$ is not even a function: $1$ will have two different values.

Comment: @0XLR I have updated the problem. Check it out. I'm still not sure I'm understanding the problem here.

Comment: Your example is different from what I said; it just uses a single constant. My example is $f(x) = \begin{cases} c_1\ &x \in [0, 1) \\ c_2\ & x \in [1, 2] \end{cases}$.

Comment: @0XLR Okay, I see. But how does that make it discontinuous? Even in the union of all the $X_i$'s, $x$ can only be located in 1 of those intervals

Comment: What do you mean? My example of $f$ above is obviously discontinuous over $[0, 1) \cup [1, 2] = [0, 2]$. It is only continuous, indeed uniformly, restricted to each interval separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sets $X_i$ are compact, you will be in good shape.  0XLR gave a counterexample in $\mathbb R$ where one of the sets was not closed.  Here is a counterexample where the sets are not bounded.

Let $$
X_1 = \{1,2,3,\dots\},
\\
X_2 = \left\{1+\frac{1}{1}, 2+\frac{1}{2}, 3+\frac{1}{3}, \dots\right\}
$$
Set $f(x) = 0$ on $X_1$ and $f(x) = 1$ on $X_2$.  Then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $X_1$ and on $X_2$, but not on $X_1 \cup X_2$.

Comment: Will this work for a union of more than 2 sets, like for $n$ sets?

Comment: Pretty sure you'd also be OK if all the sets were open, as long as there were finitely many.

Comment: Open, no good.  Take $f=1$ on $(0,1)$ and $f=0$ on $(1,2)$.

Comment: That's still continuous, because it's not defined at $1$.

Comment: But (as the OP asks) it is not uniformly continuous.